# Get text content width in parent with overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a similar functionality as Excel double clicking the column re-sizer and expanding particular column to max width of content in that column.

**Problem:** I don't know how to get text content width inside div with overflow hidden and text-overflow ellipsis. And I'm not sure what tricks I need to apply for this to work. I never tried something like this.

**Current HTML markup:**

```
<div style="width: @manuallySetWidthInPx">text</div>
```

**Current CSS:**

```
position: relative;
min-width: 50px;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

How I need to re-factor `<div />` and css to get inner text content actual width?
I'm ok with using `jQuery`.

**Note:** I'm trying to achieve this while keeping text-ellipsis, so if I need to clone that row I'm good with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a DIV and place it off screen with the following CSS

```
#two{
    width: auto !important;
    top: -100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id = "one">
    gibbfasdfsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfASDadsAS
</div>

<div id = "two">


</div>
```

Then using the following JavaScript to transfer the text of the shown DIV to the hidden DIV and grab the hidden DIV's width.

```
$(document).on("click", "#one", function(){
    var value = $("#one").text();
    $("#two").text(value);
    var div_width = $("#two").width();
    alert(div_width);
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JqcA3/2/)

Depending on the context you use the above JavaScript code, there could be some performance issues.  I don't see any problems with running a loop for 200 iterations though

Comment: In your example you open up the div. And what I want is to get that width in px without changing how the div appears. Would it be possible to duplicate this div in background set width auto then get width and then remove it? And if yes wouldn't it affect performance if I would iterate trough 200 elements cloning and removing?

Comment: @skmasq I see what you are asking for.  Check out the updated answer